# Can web developers stop IE popup dialog that Java is not installed?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, applet, popup, user-experience

I've developed a website (internal website behind a firewall) that uses a Java applet. If Java is not installed on the client, then it will fall back to other solutions.

The issue I now have is that at least IE9 pops-up a dialog saying that my webpage uses Java and how to install this. I'm already taking care of this on my webpage, so can I use some Meta tag or other to stop IE9 from ruining the user experience?

Users will think my webpage can't be run without Java when this pop-up is shown!

### HTML

```
<applet 
    id="tinyApplet" 
    width="0" 
    height="0" 
    codebase="/applet" 
    archive="se.lu.ldc.tiny.jar" 
    code="se.lu.ldc.tiny.applet.Tiny"> 
Some HTML text 
</applet>
```

Comment: Sorry, it's an internal website behind a firewall.

Comment: An extraction 

`<applet id="tinyApplet"      width="0" height="0" codebase="/applet" archive="se.lu.ldc.tiny.jar" code="se.lu.ldc.tiny.applet.Tiny">
Some HTML text
</applet>`

Comment: BTW - I edited some of your comments back into the question.  Now that I see it clearly, I would advise against trying to embed a `0x0` applet.  It is likely to be seen as suspicious, and silently removed.  Instead specify a small size (`20x20`) & use CSS to make it invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have JS check that Java is installed before ever writing the applet element.  E.G.

When you type..

```
alert(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version"));
```

In the FF JS console input line, you might see something like:

```
[02:55:46.025] alert(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.version"));
[02:55:46.027] ReferenceError: java is not defined
```

..if Java is not installed.  If it is not installed, use the alternate content/strategy.

If the call to `getProperty(String)` returns a non `null` value, then Java is installed (and `java.version` is a property defined in that JRE).

Comment: + a check if it's IE, the check didn't work in chrome for me :(

Comment: What DYM by "didn't work"?  Does that mean no Java versions was returned for a Chrome browser that had Java?  A value was returned for one that did not?  Something else?